# Splitting Mismatched Rows into Multiple Rows in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops

I would like to split the mismatched values within each column into separate rows while preserving the values in the 'Gene.ID' column for the new rows.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Gene.ID': ['NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_15', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_17', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_68', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7','NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7'],
    'DIAMOND': ['SLH', 'GT2', 'GT2', 'CBM41', 'CBM48', 'GH11', 'GH13', 'GH13', ''],
    'HMMER': ['', 'GT2', 'GT2', 'CBM41', 'CBM41', 'GH13', 'GH13', '', 'GH13'],
    'dbCAN_sub': ['', 'GT2', 'GT2', 'CBM41', 'CBM41', 'CBM41', 'CBM48', '', 'GH13']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

The result should look like this:

```
expected_data = {
    "Gene.ID": ["NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_15", "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_17", "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_68", "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7", "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7", "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7", "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7", "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7", "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7", "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7", "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7", "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7", "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7"],
    "DIAMOND": ["SLH", "GT2", "GT2", "CBM41", "CBM48", "", "GH11", "", "", "GH13", "", "GH13",""],
    "HMMER": ["", "", "GT2", "CBM41", "", "CBM41", "", "GH13", "", "GH13", "", "", "GH13"],
    "dbCAN_sub": ["", "", "GT2", "CBM41", "", "CBM41", "", "", "CBM41", "", "CBM48", "", "GH13"]
}
expected_df = pd.DataFrame(expected_data)
print(expected_df)
```

I tried this code

```
import pandas as pd
print(df)
def g(df):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if i == len(df) - 1:
            break
        if df.iloc[i, 0] == '':
            pass
        if df.iloc[i, 0] == df.iloc[i, 1]:
            pass
        if df.iloc[i, 0] != df.iloc[i, 1]:
            df.iloc[i, 1] = df.iloc[i+1, 1]
        if df.iloc[i, 1] == '':
            pass
        if df.iloc[i, 1] == df.iloc[i, 2]:
            pass
        if df.iloc[i, 1] != df.iloc[i, 2]:
            df.iloc[i, 2] = df.iloc[i+1, 2]
        
    return df

df = g(df.copy())
print(df)
```

However, I'm facing challenges in splitting the mismatched values and preserving the 'Gene.ID' column for the new rows. Can someone please help me with a solution or suggest a more efficient approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape the DataFrame and re-aggregate.

In summary, [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to get rid of the empty cells, assign a new index with [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ngroup.html), and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) back to 2D:

```
out = (df.rename_axis(index='index', columns='col')
         .set_index('Gene.ID', append=True).replace('', np.nan)
         .stack().reset_index(name='value')
         .assign(index2=lambda d: d.groupby(['index', 'Gene.ID', 'value'], sort=False).ngroup())
         .pivot(index=['Gene.ID', 'index2'], columns='col', values='value')
         .fillna('').reset_index('Gene.ID').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
                    Gene.ID DIAMOND  HMMER dbCAN_sub
0   NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_15     SLH                 
1   NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_17     GT2    GT2       GT2
2   NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_68     GT2    GT2       GT2
3    NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7   CBM41  CBM41     CBM41
4    NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7   CBM48                 
5    NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7          CBM41     CBM41
6    NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7    GH11                 
7    NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7           GH13          
8    NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7                    CBM41
9    NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7    GH13   GH13          
10   NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7                    CBM48
11   NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7    GH13                 
12   NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7           GH13      GH13
```

Comment: Ya , I got thank you, is it possible to get using loop as I did, so I will understand, where I did mistake, please provide loop way similar to my code, Thanks in advance

Comment: Ya , I realise later, I got thank you,

Comment: @Umar using a loop is not a correct approach in pandas.

Comment: Thank you, Ya, But I wanted to understand, where is my mistake, Its ok ,

Comment: @Umar well in my opinion, the loop approach **is the mistake**. Modifying a DataFrame with a loop is really inefficient or difficult. In your case, inserting rows in a loop would require complex code. If you really want to learn how to do this with loops, use lists of items, perform your loop, and reconstruct a DataFrame in the end ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ya, I did it using this, is it correct

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Gene.ID': ['NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_15', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_17', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_68', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7', 'NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7','NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7'],
    'DIAMOND': ['SLH', 'GT2', 'GT2', 'CBM41', 'CBM48', 'GH11', 'GH13', 'GH13', ''],
    'HMMER': ['', 'GT2', 'GT2', 'CBM41', 'CBM41', 'GH13', 'GH13', '', 'GH13'],
    'dbCAN_sub': ['', 'GT2', 'GT2', 'CBM41', 'CBM41', 'CBM41', 'CBM48', '', 'GH13']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)

# Initialize a list to store the resulting rows
result_rows = []

# Iterate through each row in the DataFrame
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    gene_id = row['Gene.ID']
    unique_values = set(row[1:]) - {''}
    
    if len(unique_values) > 1:
        mismatched_values = [value for value in row[1:] if value != '']
        mismatched_set = set(mismatched_values)  # Convert to set to remove duplicates
        for mismatched_value in mismatched_set:
            result_row = row.copy()
            result_row[1:] = ['' if value != mismatched_value else value for value in row[1:]]
            result_rows.append(result_row)
    else:
        result_rows.append(row)

# Create a new DataFrame from the resulting rows
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_rows)

# Reset the index of the new DataFrame
result_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Print the output
print(result_df)
```